# How to create numeronyms in bash

Tags: bash, awk, cut

I am trying to write a code that would turn any given word to its numeronym.

for example : internationalization = i18n (first char+number of chars in between+last char)

I found how to find the first and the last character and I know how to find the number part, but I don't know how to put the number between the first and the last character.

The code I used to get the number part is:

```
cut -c 2- | rev | cut -c 2- | rev | tr -d [:space:]| wc -c
```

The code I used to get the first and the last chacarters:

```
awk -F "" '{print $1,$NF}'
```

Comment: Do `a`, `an`, or `the` have numeronyms?

Comment: @JeffSchaller. `a`, `an`, `t1e`

Comment: Ah, the time saving "t1e" shortcut.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another awk solution:

```
awk '{l=length($1); print substr($1,1,1) l-2 substr($1,l,1)}'
```

- `l=length($1)` - Set the `l` variable to the length of your string (Assuming the input string is in the first column and does not contain whitespace)
- `substr($1,1,1)` - (column #, starting point, ending point) so print column 1, starting at position 1, and print 1 character.
- `l-2` - Length of string minus 2
- `substr($1,l,1)` - Print column 1 starting at position `l` (length of string) and print 1 character.

Comment: Could you explain the code please. I am just learning awk, so i don't know the substr part.

Comment: @arthionne: sure I have added explainations however I think AdminBee's answer is better than mine.  I would suggest accepting that answer.

Comment: @Jesse_b funny, I just upvoted your answer (I'm just not too sure about this "empty field separator" thing ...)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: You may want to choose a different variable for your example: `1` and `l` are a bit difficult to distinguish.

Answer (score 18):

Although I find the use of `awk` with an empty field separator somewhat 'innovative', the simplest solution in my opinion is just a small expansion of yours:

```
awk -F "" '{print $1 (NF-2) $NF}'
```

This works only with words of three or more letters, of course. To handle the general case:

```
awk -F "" '{if (NF>2) print $1 (NF-2) $NF; else print $0}'
```

As an explanation:

- By setting the field separator to "empty" with `-F ""`, the input is split into fields after every character, i.e. every character of the input is considered an individual "field" that is accessible via `$n` in *awk* expressions (with *n* being the field number ranging from 1 to `NF`). *Btw, the GNU Awk User's Guide explicitly [provides such use cases as examples](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Field-Splitting-Summary), so I stand corrected on my previous concerns about using an empty FS. Still, note that the manual says "This is a common extension; it is not specified by the POSIX standard".*
- `if` the number of fields (i.e. characters, here) is larger than two, print the first field/character (`$1`), the evaluated expression (`NF-2`) which amounts to the number of characters in between the first and the last, and the last field/character (`$NF`). Note that the `print` call as used here does not produce space between the individual output tokens; this only happens when separating the arguments with commas instead of space (see *e.g.* [the GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Print-Examples)).
- `else` simply print the entire input expression, which is accessible via `$0`

Note that if we fould feed a two-character input, *e.g.* `at`, to the first code example, we would get unwanted (but formally correct) output like `a0t` (because there are, in this case, zero characters between first and last).

**Note also**, and this is important, that if you supply a string containing leading or trailing whitespace to this `awk` call, like in `echo " hello" | awk <etc.>`, then that leading/trailing whitespace would be treated as the first/last character, thus giving unwanted behaviour!

Comment: The empty-field-separator trick does not work with BSD's version of `awk`.

Comment: Yes, I expected that something like this might happen, and that is why I quoted the warning notice from the GNU Awk manual. However, since the OP had success with this approach, I considered it safe to assume that at least _he_ is working with GNU awk or compatible ...

Comment: You can actually even use the fact that awk prints `$0` as default action, `=` returns the assigned value and no numeronym is empty (*i.e.* zero/false) to shorten the whole thing to `awk -F '' '$0=$1NF-2$NF'`

Answer (score 15):

In ksh93, bash or zsh:

```
numeronym() {
  (( ${#1} > 2 )) || return
  printf '%s%d%s\n' "${1:0:1}" "$(( ${#1} - 2 ))" "${1: -1:1}"
}
```

This works on the first (only) parameter by printing the first letter, (number of characters minus 2), and last letter.

Answer (score 5):

Portable to many shells:

```
a=internationalization;
if [ "${#a}" -gt 2 ]; then 
    a="${a%"${a#?}"}$((${#a}-2))${a#"${a%?}"}";
fi
printf '%s\n' "${a}"
```

As a function (sligtly less portable):

```
numeronym() {  a="$1";
               if [ "${#1}" -gt 2 ]; then 
                    a="${a%"${a#?}"}$((${#a}-2))${a#"${a%?}"}";
               fi;
               printf '%s\n' "${a}";
            }
```

Call it as:

```
$ numeronym internationalization
i18n
```

If it must be awk:

```
$ echo internationalization |
      awk '{ print (NF>2) ? $1 NF-2 $NF : $0 }' FS=''

i18n
```